# ContinueWith waits until main long polling Thread wakes up

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sockets, .net-4.0

The main application thread polls a server with send/receive TCP Socket:

```
public void Run(){

 var updateThreading = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                while (KeepRunning)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    try
                    {
                        // Send and receive via TCP socket
                        var response = SendAndReceive(); 
                        Callback(response);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {

                    }
                }
            });

            updateThreading.Start();
}
```

A WPF Button offers a mouse down / mouse up action managed in separated methods. On mouse down event a Task makes a server request on the same socket used by the main thread while on mouse up event I continue with the same Task to be sure that a server request of "pressure completed" is always performed.

Here is the code of the mouse down:

```
    public override void Execute_CommandDown()
    {
        DownWorkTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (!Monitor.TryEnter(SyncRoot))
            {
                return;
            } // Don't let  multiple threads in here at the same time.
            try
            {
                DoDownWork(); // send / receive via the same TCP socket of the main thread
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(SyncRoot);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's the code of the mouse up.

```
    public override void Execute_CommandUp()
    {
        // Make a continuation here...
        DownWorkTask.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (!Monitor.TryEnter(SyncRoot))
            {
                // Don't let multiple threads in here at the same time.
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                DoUpWork();// send / receive via the same TCP socket of the main thread
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(SyncRoot);
            }
        });
    }
```

The UI Thread never freezes (in my `Callback` code the `Dispatcher` updates the GUI efficiently), the Button pressed/released is reactive and the operations are performed "correctly" in sequence.
What I've noticed is that the server communication on mouse X event sometimes waits until the main thread wakes from the Sleep(1000).

What I'm expecting is an independent execution with an unique locked section on the TCP Socket and a Monitor to avoid multiple clicks (both working indeed).

I know the Task object has a "I will do this as soon as possible" semantic, but I cannot figure out why the it waits in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Is `SyncRoot` something that's coming off of one of the UI controls?  If so, I'm guessing that you're hitting an implicit UI block when syncing with a UI element.  Instead, why not just create a separate object to lock on that's completely independent of another object.

Side note, you might want to make your thread a background thread in case your application closes.

Comment: SyncRoot is an object in my Button ViewModel created for the lock purpose. I use it to avoid multiple click send on the same button and in fact the UI is reactive. +1 for the background thread tip!